# How do I add a package to an already existing image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, docker

I have a RoR app that uses imagemagick specified in the Gemfile. I am using [Docker's official rails image](https://github.com/docker-library/rails) to build my image with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM rails:onbuild
RUN apt-get install imagemagick
```

and get the following error:

```
Cant install RMagick 2.13.2. Cant find Magick-config in /usr/local/bundle/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Now, that's probably because the imagemagic package is missing on the OS, even though I specified it in my Dockerfile. So I guess the `bundle install` command is issued before my `RUN apt-get` command is issued.
My question - using this base image, is there a way to ensure imagemagic is installed prior to bundling?
Do I need to fork and change the base image Dockerfile to achieve that?

Comment: in a Dockerfile, before any install, begin with a `apt-get update` it is mandatory.

Comment: this doesn't help with the situation at hand where there's an ONBUILD scenario

Comment: you can modify a container but not an image. You can create another image, and do `FROM rails:onbuildv2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are right, the [`ONBUILD`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#onbuild) instructions from the [rails:onbuild](https://github.com/docker-library/rails/blob/940d1a7d0fc11d32aed4eb3b2cb22f62f65c6814/onbuild/Dockerfile) image will be executed just after the [`FROM`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#from) instruction of your Dockerfile.

What I suggest is to change your Dockerfile as follow:

```
FROM ruby:2.2.0
RUN apt-get install imagemagick

# throw errors if Gemfile has been modified since Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle config --global frozen 1

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-client postgresql-client sqlite3 --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


COPY Gemfile /usr/src/app/
COPY Gemfile.lock /usr/src/app/
RUN bundle install

COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["rails", "server"]
```

which I made based on the [rails:onbuild Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/rails/blob/940d1a7d0fc11d32aed4eb3b2cb22f62f65c6814/onbuild/Dockerfile) moving down the `ONBUILD` instructions and removing the `ONBUILD` flavor.

Answer (score 0):

Most packages clean out the cache to save on size.  Try this:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install imagemagick
```

Or spool up a copy of the container and look for yourself

```
docker run -it --remove <mycontainernameorid> /bin/bash
```

The --remove will ensure that the container is removed after you exit the shell.   Once in the shell look for the package binary (or dpkg --list)

Comment: the question is, given my Dockerfile above, how do I make this apt-get command execute before the "FROM" Dockerfile is executed

Comment: You cannot.    Either roll your own, or re-bundle after installing the pre-reqs.