# Bundle optimization for ruby on Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, bundler

I'm new to docker and was wondering how does ruby bundler behave when re-building docker images? The first time I build an image it takes forever to `bundle install`. What will happen when I add another gem into the Gemfile? Is there a way to ensure previous gems are cached somehow in the image and used for this  new bundling?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM rails:onbuild
RUN apt-get install -y imagemagick
```

Comment: When you did your `docker build`where you in a specific directory, like ~, with many files ? Building an image should be quick. Can you show your Dockerfile ?

Comment: Ok, so your Dockerfile is in which directory ? Can you post a `ls -al | wc -l` when you are in this directory ?

Comment: it's in my app root directory, where the rails files are (right next to the Gemfile and other 46 files)

Comment: How long does it take to build the image ?

Comment: 10 minutes. What about my question? What happens on consequent builds of the image? will all the gems be fetched again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a package to an already existing image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28027108/how-do-i-add-a-package-to-an-already-existing-image)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you `ADD` your Gemfile.

```
ADD Gemfile /var/www/yourapp/
ADD Gemfile.lock /var/www/yourapp/
RUN bundle install
```

In this case `bundle install` would only run if either the `Gemfile` or the `Gemfile.lock` changed. Note that the placement of this instruction in your Dockerfile matters. As soon as a previous build-steps cache is invalidated all subsequent instructions are no longer cached. (e.g. you `ADD` a config file before the `Gemfile`, and that changed -> bundle install will run).

> What will happen when I add another gem into the Gemfile?

If you just want to add a couple of gems without bundling everything you could also do something like:

```
ADD Gemfile /var/www/yourapp/
ADD Gemfile.lock /var/www/yourapp/
RUN bundle install
...
ADD Gemfile.tip /var/www/yourapp/
RUN bundle install
```

[Here is a rails example project you can check out (well documented).](https://github.com/cpuguy83/docker-rails-dev-demo/blob/master/Dockerfile)

Comment: what does that gemfile.tip comes from? bundler or docker?

Comment: @juanpastasfrom that example project I posted. You generate the `.tip` file yourself.

Comment: @wpp looks like you are just postponing the problem. If Gemfile.tip changes you'd have to run bundle install again taking a long time if .tip had a lot of gems. You could argue that .tip has to be kept small but than, when you need more packages what would you do?Add yet another file and another RUN bundle install?